# Why is logical "or" not working with regex?

Tags: javascript, json, regex, debugging

So im searching through a JSON file and returning all of the Title's that contain an inputed value. I also want to make it so that it returns any record that has the inputed value in the description so I assumed that if i used a logical "or" it would return records with the input value in the title AND in the description; However it doesn't seem to be working.

Code Just searching the Title:

```
    function search() {
//connects to API endpoint
$("#tbody tr").remove();
var request2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
var accessToken = 'my token';
request2.open('GET', 'my url');
caryID = this.id;
request2.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
//function that stores the JSON reply into a variable
request2.onload = function () {
    var sName = document.getElementById('searchBar').value;
    var sName = sName.toUpperCase()
    var regex = new RegExp(sName, "i");
    var results = [];
    var data = JSON.parse(this.response)
    if (request2.status >= 200 && request2.status < 400) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

            var entry = data[i]["fields"]["Title"].toUpperCase();
            if (entry.search(regex) != -1) {
                var id = data[i]["id"];
                var title = data[i]["fields"]["Title"];
                var desc = data[i]["fields"]["Synopsis"];
                var location = data[i]["fields"]["Location"];
                var copyYear = data[i]["fields"]["Copyrightyear"];
                document.getElementById('tbody').innerHTML += `<tr><td>${id}</td> <td>${title}</td> <td>${location}</td> <td>${desc}</td> <td>${copyYear}</td> </tr>`
                //document.getElementById("JSON").innerText += JSON.stringify(data[i]["id"]) + JSON.stringify(data[i]["fields"]["Title"]) + "         " + JSON.stringify(data[i]["fields"]["Synopsis"]);
                // alert(data[i]["id"] + data[i]["fields"]["Title"] + data[i]["fields"]["Synopsis"] )
            }
        }

            totalRecords = 10000;
            searchOverflow();

    } else {
        alert('error');
    }
}
request2.send();
```

}

The output: [correct Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlfCH.png)

As you can see it does what its supposed to; However whenever I use a logical or, it stops working.

Code when I add the OR:

```
    function search() {
//connects to API endpoint
$("#tbody tr").remove();
var request2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
var accessToken = 'my token';
request2.open('GET', 'my url');
caryID = this.id;
request2.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
//function that stores the JSON reply into a variable
request2.onload = function () {
    var sName = document.getElementById('searchBar').value;
    var sName = sName.toUpperCase()
    var regex = new RegExp(sName, "i");
    var results = [];
    var data = JSON.parse(this.response)
    if (request2.status >= 200 && request2.status < 400) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

            var entry = data[i]["fields"]["Title"].toUpperCase();
            var description = data[i]["fields"]["Synopsis"].toUpperCase(); 
            if (entry.search(regex) != -1 || description.search(regex) != -1) {
                var id = data[i]["id"];
                var title = data[i]["fields"]["Title"];
                var desc = data[i]["fields"]["Synopsis"];
                var location = data[i]["fields"]["Location"];
                var copyYear = data[i]["fields"]["Copyrightyear"];
                document.getElementById('tbody').innerHTML += `<tr><td>${id}</td> <td>${title}</td> <td>${location}</td> <td>${desc}</td> <td>${copyYear}</td> </tr>`
                //document.getElementById("JSON").innerText += JSON.stringify(data[i]["id"]) + JSON.stringify(data[i]["fields"]["Title"]) + "         " + JSON.stringify(data[i]["fields"]["Synopsis"]);
                // alert(data[i]["id"] + data[i]["fields"]["Title"] + data[i]["fields"]["Synopsis"] )
            }
        }

            totalRecords = 10000;
            searchOverflow();

    } else {
        alert('error');
    }
}
request2.send();
```

}

The output: [incorrect output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZnl7.png)

As you can see the output is blank. Any ideas on why this would be the case?

Comment: Please include your code in the question itself rather posting images of your code.

Comment: sorry about that i just updated it

Comment: "*I assumed that if i used a logical "or" it would return records with the input value in the title AND in the description*" - I don't get it. Why did you plan to use OR when you say that you want the title **AND** the description to match?

Comment: I have to admit though that when using OR (`||`), it still should have shown the same entries (if not more) as when matching only the title, when searching for the same keyword.